# How to create multi-filtering for mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an online game store and code that filters data by tags and genres. But I also want to add filtering by platforms and systems. For example, the system is PC and the platform is Steam. How can I implement this?

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const slug = require('mongoose-slug-updater');
const options = {
    separator: "-",
    lang: "en",
    truncate: 120
}
mongoose.plugin(slug, options);
const GamesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    slug: { type: String, slug: ["title"], slugPaddingSize: 2, unique: true },
    last_url: String,
    description: String,
    preview: {
        src: String,
        alt: String
    },
    stock_price: String,
    discount: Number,
    total_price: String,
    system: Array,
    platform: String,
    info: {
        Genre: Array
    },
    tags: Array,
    config: Object,
    images: Array,
    keys: Array,
    content: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Games", GamesSchema);
```

**api controller**

```
async get(req, res) {
        try {
            const page = parseInt(req.query.page) - 1 || 0;
            const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5;
            const search = req.query.search || '';
            let sort = req.query.sort || "top";
            let tags = req.query.tags || 'all';
            const tagsOpt = [];
            Games.find().then(async games => {
                games.forEach(game => {
                    game.tags.forEach(tag => {
                        if (!tagsOpt.includes(tag)) {
                            tagsOpt.push(tag)
                        }
                    })
                })

                tags === 'all' ? (tags = [...tagsOpt]) : (tags = req.query.tags.split(','));
                req.query.sort ? (sort = req.query.sort.split(',')) : (sort = [sort]);

                let sortBy = {};
                if (sort[1]) {
                    sortBy[sort[0] = sort[1]];
                } else {
                    sortBy[sort[0] = "top"]
                }
                const gamesData = await Games.find({ title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } })
                    .where('tags')
                    .in([...tags])
                    .sort(sortBy)
                    .skip(page * limit)
                    .limit(limit);

                const total = await Games.countDocuments({
                    tags: { $in: [...tags] },
                    title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
                });
                const response = {
                    error: false,
                    total,
                    page: page + 1,
                    limit,
                    tags: tagsOpt,
                    gamesData
                };
                res.status(200).json(response);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'Ошибка получения' })
        }
    }
```

I was able to combine genres and tags into one and filter by them, do I really now need to put both the platform and the systems into an array of tags?

Comment: you can use $facet operator in aggregation.which will do multiple filter parallely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to put both the platform and the systems into an array of tags. You can filter by platform and system separately.

You can add two more query parameters for platform and system in your API and then use them in your mongoose query. Here's how you can do it:

```
async get(req, res) {
    try {
        const page = parseInt(req.query.page) - 1 || 0;
        const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5;
        const search = req.query.search || '';
        let sort = req.query.sort || "top";
        let tags = req.query.tags || 'all';
        const platform = req.query.platform || '';
        const system = req.query.system || '';
        const tagsOpt = [];
        Games.find().then(async games => {
            games.forEach(game => {
                game.tags.forEach(tag => {
                    if (!tagsOpt.includes(tag)) {
                        tagsOpt.push(tag)
                    }
                })
            })

            tags === 'all' ? (tags = [...tagsOpt]) : (tags = req.query.tags.split(','));
            req.query.sort ? (sort = req.query.sort.split(',')) : (sort = [sort]);

            let sortBy = {};
            if (sort[1]) {
                sortBy[sort[0] = sort[1]];
            } else {
                sortBy[sort[0] = "top"]
            }
            const gamesData = await Games.find({ 
                title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
                platform: { $regex: platform, $options: 'i' },
                system: { $in: system.split(',') }
            })
                .where('tags')
                .in([...tags])
                .sort(sortBy)
                .skip(page * limit)
                .limit(limit);

            const total = await Games.countDocuments({
                tags: { $in: [...tags] },
                title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
                platform: { $regex: platform, $options: 'i' },
                system: { $in: system.split(',') }
            });
            const response = {
                error: false,
                total,
                page: page + 1,
                limit,
                tags: tagsOpt,
                gamesData
            };
            res.status(200).json(response);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Ошибка получения' })
    }
}
```

In this code, I've added two new query parameters platform and system. The platform is a string and system is an array. I've used $regex for platform to make it case-insensitive and $in for system to match any system in the array.

Now, you can filter games by platform and system by adding platform and system parameters in your API request like this: /api/games?platform=Steam&system=PC,Mac.

Please replace the file path with your actual file path.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!) This solution works, but I did it a little differently, since I need the search by platforms and systems to be a multi-search, that is, I could filter simultaneously for PC, Xbox, as well as for Steam Origin platforms, etc. So I did this:

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) - 1 || 0;
        const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5;
        const search = req.query.search || '';
        let sort = req.query.sort || "rating";
        let tags = req.query.tags || 'all';
        let system = req.query.system || 'all';
        let platform = req.query.platform || 'all';
        let language = req.query.language || 'all';
        const tagsOpt = [];
        const platformOpt = [];
        const systemOpt = [];
        const languageOpt = [];
        Games.find().then(async games => {
            games.forEach(game => {
                game.tags.forEach(tag => {
                    if (!tagsOpt.includes(tag)) {
                        tagsOpt.push(tag)
                    }
                })
                if (!platformOpt.includes(game.platform)) {
                    platformOpt.push(game.platform)
                }
                if (!systemOpt.includes(game.system)) {
                    systemOpt.push(game.system)
                }
                game.languages.forEach(language => {
                    if (!languageOpt.includes(language)) {
                        languageOpt.push(language)
                    }
                })
            })

            tags === 'all' ? (tags = [...tagsOpt]) : (tags = req.query.tags.split(','));
            platform === 'all' ? (platform = [...platformOpt]) : (platform = req.query.platform.split(','));
            system === 'all' ? (system = [...systemOpt]) : (system = req.query.system.split(','));
            language === 'all' ? (language = [...languageOpt]) : (language = req.query.language.split(','));
            req.query.sort ? (sort = req.query.sort.split(',')) : (sort = [sort]);

            let sortBy = {};
            if (sort[1]) {
                sortBy[sort[0]] = sort[1];
            } else {
                sortBy[sort[0]] = "asc";
            }
            const gamesData = await Games.find({ title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } })
                .where('tags').in([...tags])
                .where('platform').in([...platform])
                .where('system').in([...system])
                .where('languages').in([...language])
                .sort(sortBy)
                .skip(page * limit)
                .limit(limit);

            const total = await Games.countDocuments({
                tags: { $in: [...tags] },
                title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
            });
            const response = {
                error: false,
                total,
                page: page + 1,
                limit,
                tags: tagsOpt,
                language: languageOpt,
                platform: platformOpt,
                system: systemOpt,
                gamesData
            };
            res.status(200).json(response);
        })
```

Or can I optimize this?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is performing a lot of operations that could be optimized. Here are some suggestions:

Use MongoDB's aggregation framework: The aggregation framework is a powerful tool that allows you to perform complex transformations and computations on your data directly in the database. This can be much faster than retrieving the data and processing it in your application.
Avoid unnecessary database calls: Your code is currently calling Games.find() twice, once to get the options for tags, platform, system, and language, and once to get the actual games data. You can reduce this to a single call by using the aggregation framework.
Use projection to limit the fields returned by the database: If you only need certain fields from your documents, you can use projection to limit the fields that are returned. This can reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred from the database to your application, which can improve performance.

Here's an example of how you might implement these suggestions:

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) - 1 || 0;
const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5;
const search = req.query.search || '';
let sort = req.query.sort || "rating";
let tags = req.query.tags || 'all';
let system = req.query.system || 'all';
let platform = req.query.platform || 'all';
let language = req.query.language || 'all';

tags = tags === 'all' ? [] : tags.split(',');
platform = platform === 'all' ? [] : platform.split(',');
system = system === 'all' ? [] : system.split(',');
language = language === 'all' ? [] : language.split(',');
platform = platform === 'all' ? [] : platform.split(',');
system = system === 'all' ? [] : system.split(',');

sort = sort.split(',');
let sortBy = {};
if (sort[1]) {
    sortBy[sort[0]] = sort[1];
} else {
    sortBy[sort[0]] = "asc";
}

const pipeline = [
    { $match: { title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } } },
    { $match: { platform: { $in: platform } } },
    { $match: { system: { $in: system } } },
    { $match: { tags: { $in: tags } } },
    { $match: { platform: { $in: platform } } },
    { $match: { system: { $in: system } } },
    { $match: { languages: { $in: language } } },
    { $sort: sortBy },
    { $skip: page * limit },
    { $limit: limit },
    { $project: { /* specify the fields you need here */ } }
];

const gamesData = await Games.aggregate(pipeline).exec();

const total = await Games.countDocuments({
    tags: { $in: tags },
    title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' },
});

const response = {
    error: false,
    total,
    page: page + 1,
    limit,
    gamesData
};

res.status(200).json(response);
```

This code uses the aggregation framework to perform all of the filtering, sorting, and pagination directly in the database. It also uses projection to limit the fields that are returned, although you'll need to fill in the fields you need in the $project stage.

Please note that this code assumes that if 'all' is passed for tags, platform, system, or language, it means that any value is acceptable for that field. If 'all' should be treated as a specific value, you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.

Also, this code doesn't include the options for tags, platform, system, and language in the response. If you still need these options, you could consider caching them to avoid having to compute them every time.